# Data based indexed column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I had big tables that had index on date based column , my question is am trying to select from this table the data of yesterday as "`where date=trunc(sysdate-1)`" or similar condition , the problem is its taking forever for result , making suspect the index isn't working for some reason , do you have any suggestion , many thanks.

NB,this table is old no need for analyze

Comment: You'll need to add way more details. As it is, all we know is that something is taking a long time... (Table structure, index definition(s), row count, cardinality of indexed columns, actual query and explain plan, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To know index is used to read data , you have to generate the plan for you SQL . Try to generate SQL plan and post,  as below:

```
SQL>SET PAGESIZE 500;
SQL>set linesize 500;

SQL>select * from your_table where ....bla bla ;

SQL>select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor());
```